# Rerun Scala code with -deprecation using Apache Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using a Zeppelin notebook to create a Spark script in Scala.

Code:

```
def test: DataFrame= {

     //code

}
```

I am getting the following warning:

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details.
```

Any suggestions of how to run the function with "-deprecation"?

PS. I'm not asking about the warning which will require the complete code of the function. I'm looking for suggestions on how to rerun the function with the depreciation parameter in a zeppelin notebook. Existing solutions for this question covers only running in SBT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Spark interpreter settings in Zeppelin there is a "args" property that can be set. This corresponds to Spark commandline arguments which is what to change in this case. More infomration about possible configurations can be found in the documentation [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#configuration).

In short, add "-deprecation" as value for the **args property** and you will be able to see the details.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work by adding "-deprecation" (with or without quotation marks) via the zeppelin ui, in menu [username]->Interpreter->(search for spark)-> edit add -deprecation to args box. Is this what you meant? "warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details" shows in the paragraph regardless with no other information.